# Setting up a dictionary within a lambda expression based upon a file

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am working on a project that features a lot of code and am using it as a means to learn. I am doing this by picking it apart and playing with it

One part of the code initially featured this

```
def removeQuotesAndCommmasFromString(line):
if line.startswith('"'):
    line = line[1:]
if line.endswith(','):
    line = line[:-2]
if line.endswith('"'):
    line = line[:-2]
return line

DUMMY = {l[0].strip().strip('\n'):l[1].strip().strip('\n').split("~") for l in map(lambda x: removeQuotesAndCommmasFromString(x).split("\t"),open(sys.argv[3]).readlines()) if len(l)==2}
```

I cant kick the whole code off from the command line however and use it to learn so would like to take this and adapt it to read in the file another way. I have therefore done the following however the code I have below errors due to invalid systax where I use removeQuotesAndCommas.

```
def removeQuotesAndCommmasFromString(line):
if line.startswith('"'):
    line = line[1:]
if line.endswith(','):
    line = line[:-2]
if line.endswith('"'):
    line = line[:-2]
return line    

DUMMY1 = {l[0].strip().strip('\n'):l[1].strip().strip('\n').split("~") for l in map(lambda x: removeQuotesAndCommmasFromString(x).split("\t"),pd.read_csv('filename.csv') if len(l)==2}
```

I have also tried

```
DUMMY1 = {l[0].strip().strip('\n'):l[1].strip().strip('\n').split("~") for l in map(lambda x: removeQuotesAndCommmasFromString(x).split("\t"),open('filename.csv') if len(l)==2}
```

Any ideas as to how I can get the information I need that comes from a certain file into this line?

Comment: "the code doesn't like me" is not an adequate problem statement.

Comment: Maybe you should write a function instead of 184 length one-liner

Comment: Why are you using `pandas` here, anyway? `map` on a `pd.DataFrame` isn't going to do what you want.

Comment: i have also tried using `open('filename.csv'`) but that doesn't work either

Comment: "It doesn't work" **is not an adequate problem statement**

Comment: What more can I say?

Comment: Can we get something like what your input CSV is and an output of how you want your dictionary to look after parsing the CSV?

Comment: @Taylrl seriously? Look, being able to communicate your problems to other people is a *critical skill* for any programmer. At the *very least* you should be able to describe what you are trying to accomplish, your inputs, your **expected outputs**, your actual output, or any errors you are getting (including a full stack trace).

Comment: Your one-liners don't fit on the screen, and it's hard to tell what you want. You need to put some effort into asking questions. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: Give me a minute I will edit the question

Comment: You *should always post the exact errors you are getting, with the full stack trace*, but I'm pretty sure you are just missing a closing parenthesis. However, note that your attempt to use a dataframe is going to not work out like you expect.

Comment: Ok. I this question has clearly been a bit of a disaster. Thanks for your help and I guess I will chalk this up to experience! :)